# How do I configure Strapi and NGINX routing for a subdomain?

Tags: nginx, url-routing, strapi

I am looking for assistance with configuring subdomains and routing for a server hosting my Strapi app. The server has two subdomains, **admin.website.com** and **api.website.com**. Currently, the app is running on port `1338` at http://localhost:1338.

I need to configure the API to be accessible through api.website.com and the admin page to be accessible through admin.website.com. Essentially, I want to map the local URLs to their respective subdomains:

| **Local URL** | **Subdomain URL** |
| --- | --- |
| http://localhost:1338/api/blog-article | http://api.website.com/blog-article |
| http://localhost:1338/admin | http://admin.website.com |
| http://localhost:1338/admin/content-manager/collectionType/api::blog-article.blog-article | http://admin.website.com/content-manager/collectionType/api::blog-article.blog-article |
| http://localhost:1338/admin/auth/login | http://admin.website.com/auth/login |

I have started implementing the configuration using NGINX. For the API, the configuration was straightforward. I created a configuration file for api.website.com and used `proxy_pass` to redirect requests to http://localhost:1338. After restarting NGINX, the API was successfully available at http://api.website.com/blog-article.

However, I encountered difficulties configuring the admin page. I tried adjusting the `url` parameter in the project's configuration files (*config/admin.js* and *config/server.js*), but it did not yield the desired result.

One of the attempts I made was setting the `url` parameter to `/` in *config/admin.js*, hoping to bypass the welcome page and directly display the admin page. Unfortunately, I received an error indicating that a pathname is required.

As a temporary solution, I made the following updates to the configurations:

In *config/admin.js*, I removed the `url` parameter.
In the NGINX configuration file for admin.website.com, I added `rewrite` rules to remove the `/admin` path.
With these changes, I can access the admin page at http://admin.website.com. However, the links within the admin pages still contain the `/admin` path, which is the default value set in *config/admin.js*.

```js
// config/admin.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  auth: {
    secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
  },
  apiToken: {
    salt: env('API_TOKEN_SALT'),
  }
});
```

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/admin.website.com.conf

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name admin.website.com;

  location / {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:1338;
    rewrite /(.+) /$1 break;
    rewrite / /admin break;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

As a result, the URLs appear as follows:

- Instead of http://admin.website.com/content-manager/collectionType/api::blog-article.blog-article, it shows http://admin.website.com/admin/content-manager/collectionType/api::blog-article.blog-article.
- Instead of http://admin.website.com/auth/login, it shows http://admin.website.com/admin/auth/login.

...and so on.

I would appreciate guidance on how to properly configure the routing to fix the admin page paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it’s not that easy sadly, the admin url is postfix of server url. You prolly have to do a redirection middleware:

https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/nginx-proxy#redirecting-landing-page-to-admin-panel

But you gonna need to add whole a lot of routes.

Also you have to take in consideration that `/api` should be:

`https://api.your-domain.com/api` because strapi would use `https://api.your-domain.com` for plugin routes (you can check witch routes are used by `yarn strapi routes:list`).

So technically it would be easier to redirect `/api`, `/uploads` and keep strapi under `admin.your-domain.com`